# How do I get python to search a csv file for items in a dictionary then print out the entire excel row...Thanks

Tags: excel, csv, python-3.x, dictionary, report

Trying to get python to search a csv file for a specific phone number in a dictionary and then return the entire excel row. Thank you.

Example code:

```
import csv

def generateKnownReport(mypath, GKR):
    if GKR==True:
        with open("fileName.csv") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')  
            file_one = list(reader)
        affiliate_phone_dict = {"xxx-xxx-xxxx":"Name 1","yyy-yyy-yyyy":"Name 2"}
        federal_phone_dict = {}
        for row in file_one:
            for each in row:
                search(affiliate_phone_dict,each)

def search(myDict, lookup):
    with open('KnownReport.csv','w') as f:
        for key, value in myDict.items():
            for value in key, value:
                if lookup in key:
                    f.write('{0}\n'.format(value))
                    f.write('{0}\n'.format(lookup))
     return 




GKR=True
mypath="November2013 T-Mobile Statement - Daily Detail.csv"
generateKnownReport(mypath, GKR)
```

Just to be clear I am trying to get python to write the entire line of the CSV file to the output file and not just the thing it was searching for. So for example, if I was searching in this csv file:

```
Date        Time Length Cost   Bill Category                                      Destination Number Destination City Origin Number Origin City Type

01/01/0001  10:37   3   $0.00   LOCAL AIRTIME, LONG DISTANCE and INTERNATIONAL CHARGES  xxx-xxx-xxxx    City Name   aaa-aaa-aaaa    City Name   Mobile

01/01/0001  10:37   10  $0.00   LOCAL AIRTIME, LONG DISTANCE and INTERNATIONAL CHARGES  yyy-yyy-yyyy    City Name   zzz-zzz-zzzz    City Name   Mobile
```

For the numbers xxx-xxx-xxxx and yyy-yyy-yyyy, I would want a line of code that prints out the entire row that those numbers were found on. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What works and doesn't work in your code? If an error is thrown, can you provide the (complete) traceback?

Comment: Yes, sorry. So my question is how one would code it to make python print the entire excel row where it found the value. When I run it, it works to the extent that it writes the name and number if it finds it in the file.

However, as previously stated I am trying to get it to print the entire line of the excel file. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do. Can you update your question with a sample csv file and your expected output? It would be nice if you could update your question with the comment above also, so that future visitors don't have to read the comments in order to understand the question and the answers :)

Comment: I apologize, I am trying to explain myself, but it is proving rather difficult to get my point across. Thanks :)

Comment: Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Update: I still am looking for help for this program, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but if you want to print each row that contains any of the numbers in `affiliate_phone_dict`, this will do:

```
lookup = {'name1': 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
          'name2': 'yyy-yyy-yyyy'}

with open('data.csv') as data_file, open('out.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    for row in data_file:
        if any(num in row for num in lookup.values()):
            out_file.write(row)
```

**data.csv**

```
Date Time Length Cost Bill Category Destination Number Destination City Origin Number OriginCity
01/01/0001  10:37   3   $0.00   LOCAL AIRTIME, LONG DISTANCE and INTERNATIONAL CHARGES  xxx-xxx-xxxx    City Name   aaa-aaa-aaaa    City Name   Mobile
01/01/0001  10:37   10  $0.00   LOCAL AIRTIME, LONG DISTANCE and INTERNATIONAL CHARGES  yyy-yyy-yyyy    City Name   zzz-zzz-zzzz    City Name   Mobile
01/01/0001  10:37   10  $0.00   LOCAL AIRTIME, LONG DISTANCE and INTERNATIONAL CHARGES  123-456-7890    City Name   zzz-zzz-zzzz    City Name   Mobile
```

**out.csv**

```
01/01/0001  10:37   3   $0.00   LOCAL AIRTIME, LONG DISTANCE and INTERNATIONAL CHARGES  xxx-xxx-xxxx    City Name   aaa-aaa-aaaa    City Name   Mobile
01/01/0001  10:37   10  $0.00   LOCAL AIRTIME, LONG DISTANCE and INTERNATIONAL CHARGES  yyy-yyy-yyyy    City Name   zzz-zzz-zzzz    City Name   Mobile
```

Comment: I tried but this is not working.
This is the code I now have:

`affiliate_phone_dict = {"xxx-xxx-xxxx":"Name 1","yyy-yyy-yyyy":"Name 2"}
with open("November2013 T-Mobile Statement - Daily Detail EDITED.csv") as dataFile:
           ##reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')  
           ##file_one = list(reader)    
           for row in dataFile:
               for each in row:
                   search(affiliate_phone_dict, each, row)        
def search(myDict, lookup, row):
   with open('KnownReport.csv','w') as f:
       if any(num in row for num in myDict.values()):
           f.write(row)`

Comment: I apologize for the code above, but I am bad at formatting on this site.

Comment: @nCodeProgrammer I'm sorry, but SO isn't your personal debugger.. :) Try my code, confirm that it works *by itself*, then try to implement small parts of it one at a time. Use a debugger (preferable) or insert print statements so that you know what's happening in your code. A great read is this [blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. I'd suggest that you read it.